# Nonlinear ODE with integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My question is to find the function $f(t)$ such that $$\frac{df}{dt} = -2f(t)\int_{0}^{t}f(s)\, ds$$ with $f(0) = 1$.

My idea is to divide both sides by $-2f$ and differentiate both sides, and then let $g = \frac{df}{dt}$ and consider $g$ as a function of $f$ which would reduce the order of the differential equation, but this doesn't seem to be working. Is this the right way? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if your way works or not, but here is how I would do it.  Define $F(t)=\int_0^t f(s)\,ds$.  The ODE becomes $F''(t)=-2F'(t)F(t)=-\frac{d}{dt}(F(t)^2)$.  Integrate both sides, get $F'(t)=-F(t)^2+c$.  $F(0) = 0$ and $F'(0) = f(0) = 1$, so $c=1$, and $\frac{dF}{dt}=1-F^2$.  This is a first-order separable ODE that can be solved by separation of variables.

Comment: This is much simpler. Thanks!